# Next image function not displaying on calling in on drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three `div` elements with a class of `.box` and ids `10`, `11`, `12`. I also have `.box002` with an id of `2`.

On dragging `.box002` to any of the `.box` elements the `background-color` and `p` element get deleted. On drop I have called the `nextslide()` function to display the next slide if the drop is successful, but it didn't work.

I want to display the next image for dragging if the drop is successful.

How can I achieve it?

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

var x = document.get

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  alert(data);
  var el = document.getElementById(data);

  el.parentNode.removeChild(el); // deleting drag item

  ev.target.style.backgroundColor = 'initial'; //[value indicate which box elemenet] bgcoclor none

  var pParagraph = ev.target.firstElementChild;
  console.log(pParagraph);
  ev.target.removeChild(pParagraph);

  nextslide();
}

var images = new Array();
images[0] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";
images[1] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";
images[2] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";
var currentpic = 0;
var lastpic = images.length - 1;

function nextslide() {
  if (currentpic == lastpic) {
    currentpic = 0;
    document.getElementById('slide').src = images[currentpic];
  } else {
    currentpic++;
    document.getElementById('slide').src = images[currentpic];
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: coral;
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: #b3b300;
  margin: -2px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #42e0fd;
}

.box002 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  background-color: #333 2px;
  margin-bottom: 40%;
}

.text {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 7 px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 30%;
}

p {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
    <p name="values">12</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
    <p name="values">21</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
    <p name="values">17</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2" onclick="nextslide()">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" draggable="true" id="slide" style="width:100px; height:100px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
</div>
```

Comment: You are removing the dragged image of the DOM in `el.parentNode.removeChild(el);`.
Then in `nextslide` the element is not found and an error i thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for an interesting and very fun problem. As Mario Vázquez rightly pointed out, you were deleting the image then trying to reference it later. I have been looking at this problem since you posted it and hadn't realized that was where it was going wrong. After that though, there was another bug with your text deletion. The thing you were trying to delete, `firstElementChild` isn't actually a node, it's an element. So when you were calling the command `removeChild`, it couldn't function because that command only deletes nodes.

To fix this, just replace the `firstElementChild` with `firstChild`. That is an easy fix. Then remove `el.parentNode.removeChild(el)` to solve the deleting of the image before you actually call it in your code.

Hope this helps.
From
Your friendly neighborhood Internet Guy

Comment: Also forgot to add that the boxes seem to move upwards whenever the picture is placed inside of them. Don't know if that is what you wanted. Also, you may want to find a new way to generate your images as the current method you're using duplicates its self. This is most likely due to how the website generates images. I tested adding in some different images and leaving the random ones in and it worked fine so it is probably just a website issue. My suggestion would be to have a random number generator and allocate set images and randomly assign them to the array. That's all, thanks for reading

Comment: yeah i now understand the mistake,  thanks by the way.